# Need to get sum of value of all records in one table based on max status value of one record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

CP has

```
FIELD_ID | Acreage | CROP_CLASS
001-0485 | 7.62536 |  RATOON
004-1156 | 9.64524 |  PLANTCANE
002-8512 | 3.69851 |  RATOON
005-1151 | 2.89748 |  RATOON
```

DT has

```
 farmer_bsi |parcel_id  |  crop_season    | tonnage_adjusted | parcel_status
859         |  001-8596 |       3         |     251.252      |    1
 78         |  002-8512 |       2         |      51.252      |    3
 89         |  004-1156 |       3         |     151.252      |    2
 89         |  004-1156 |       3         |     11.252       |    3
85          |  005-1151 |       3         |     10.85        |    3
```

Farmers

```
ASSN | farmer_bsi 
CPC | 859
BBZ | 85
```

I need the crop class, sum of tonnage_adjusted and sum of acreage of all parcels which have a max parcel_status of 3 from the DT table by crop class and association. Status 3 means closed. The first table also has farmer_bsi

IE. from above I would need to render as

```
Closed    | SumofAcreage | SumofTonnage
PLANTCANE | 9.64524      | 162.504
RATOON    | 6.59599      |  62.102 




**Code i use to get results**


SELECT CROP_CLASS As Closed, SUM(ACREAGE) AS SumofAcreage, SUM(delivered)       AS SumofTonnage
FROM dbo.vCurrentParcelStatus 
WHERE CropSeasonsID = 3 AND CURRENTSTATUS = '3'
GROUP BY CROP_CLASS
ORDER BY CROP_CLASS ASC



**vCurrentParcelStatus**



SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.CaneParcel.geoid, MAX(dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.CurrentStatus) AS CURRENTSTATUS, dbo.CaneParcel.ACREAGE, 
                  dbo.CaneParcel.VARIETY, dbo.CaneParcel.FARMER, dbo.CaneParcel.BRANCH, dbo.CaneParcel.DATE_PLANT, dbo.CaneParcel.CROP_CLASS, 
                  SUM(ROUND(dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.delivered, 1)) AS delivered, SUM(dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.number_deliveries) AS number_deliveries, 
                  dbo.CaneParcel.ASSN, dbo.CaneParcel.PRODUCTION, dbo.CaneParcel.REAPING_LE, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id, 
                  dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.crop_season, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.CropSeasonsID
FROM         dbo.CaneParcel INNER JOIN
                  dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp ON dbo.CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id
GROUP BY dbo.CaneParcel.geoid, dbo.CaneParcel.ACREAGE, dbo.CaneParcel.VARIETY, dbo.CaneParcel.FARMER, dbo.CaneParcel.BRANCH, dbo.CaneParcel.DATE_PLANT, 
                  dbo.CaneParcel.CROP_CLASS, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id, dbo.CaneParcel.ASSN, dbo.CaneParcel.PRODUCTION, dbo.CaneParcel.REAPING_LE, 
                  dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.crop_season, dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.CropSeasonsID
ORDER BY dbo.vCurrentParcelStatusHelp.parcel_id


**vCurrentParcelStatusHelp**


SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT MAX(parcel_status) AS CurrentStatus, COUNT(tonnage) AS number_deliveries, SUM(tonnage_adjusted) AS delivered, parcel_id, 
                  farmer_owner_bsi, crop_season, CropSeasonsID
FROM         dbo.vDeliveryTons
GROUP BY parcel_id, farmer_owner_bsi, crop_season, CropSeasonsID
ORDER BY parcel_id
```

The first 2 code above are views the first is used in the other above and lastly on my code which i use as third above. However your code does not seem to replicate what i get with my code.

From the code directly above i calculate max parcel status and from the other i use in my code to get sum of tonnage and acreage. However i cant seem to replicate this using your codes below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward Group By

```
Create Table #cp
(
Field_ID VarChar(15),
Acreage Float,
Crop_Class VarChar(15)
)
Insert Into #cp Values
('001-0485',7.62536,'RATOON'),
('004-1156',9.64524,'PLANTCANE'),
('002-8512',3.69851,'RATOON'),
('005-1151',2.89748,'RATOON')

Create Table #dt
(
farmer_bsi Int,
parcel_id VarChar(15),
crop_season Int,
tonnage_adjusted Float,
parcel_status Int
)
Insert Into #dt Values
(859,'001-8596',3,251.252,1),
(78,'002-8512',2,51.252,3),
(85,'004-1156',3,151.252,2),
(89,'004-1156',3,11.252,3),
(85,'005-1151',3,10.85,3)


Create Table #farmers
(
assn VarChar(5),
farmer_bsi Int
)
Insert Into #farmers Values
('CPC',859),
('BBZ',85)
```

Query: UPDATED to include a join to only the parcel IDs that have a status of 3.  this should then sum all parcel records for those with at least one rec status of 3

```
Select 
   #cp.Crop_Class As Closed, 
   Sum(#cp.Acreage) as SumOfTonnage,
   Sum(#dt.tonnage_adjusted) as SumOfTonnage
From 
   #cp Left Join
   #dt On #dt.parcel_id  = #cp.Field_ID Left Join
   #farmers f On f.farmer_bsi = #dt.farmer_bsi Join
   (Select Distinct #dt.parcel_id From #dt Where parcel_status = 3) c On c.parcel_id = #cp.Field_ID
Group By 
   #cp.Crop_Class
```

Result:

```
Closed      SumOfTonnage    SumOfTonnage
PLANTCANE   19.29048        162.504
RATOON      6.59599         62.102
```

Comment: your query is giving me the sum of tonnage times 3 @level3looper

Comment: @ivias, Perhaps I misrepresented your data in some way... Can you confirm you're using the same information I provided?  If you copy everything I provided, it will produce the result I provided.  One note, is that the PLANTCANE tonnage in my result of [11.252] is less than your result of [162.504].  This is because I selected only the parcels with a status of [3 - Closed].

Comment: Okay, the query isnt adding the values of the other parcel statuses with 1, 2 etc. Plant cane should be 162.504 as there are 2 entries with the same FIELD_ID these two should be summed. One entry has status 2 and the other 2 but we want to sum once there is a max parcel_status entry of 3. Once there is an entry of 3 that means parcel is closed so we need to add the sum of all the other fields even if they have parcel_status 1 or 2 @level3looper

Comment: Its giving me huge results which is not what i expected. @level3looper

Comment: I also need to make sure crop_season = 3, if i put this as a where clause outside the DISTINCT i get an timeout error.

Comment: Also if i remove distinct from the query it still gives me the same result

Comment: I added my code which i used to get results but yours still doesnt match mine. @level3looper

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, I had to double check my script as I got a different result to you.

You mentioned only wanted parcel_status = 3 but you seem to be including a status of 2 in your results.

If you require 2 & 3 then swap the "= 3" part on the join to either "<> 1" or if there are other values that could be in there too then "IN (2,3)"

Also, based on the results required, I don't see any need for the Farmers table in this query unless you wanted results per farmer also, but that would be a different report.

```
    SELECT
    CP.CROP_CLASS AS Closed
    ,SUM(CP.Acreage) AS SumofAcreage
    ,SUM(DT.tonnage_adjusted ) AS SumofTonnage
    FROM CP
    INNER JOIN DT ON CP.FIELD_ID = DT.parcel_id AND parcel_status <= 3
    GROUP BY CROP_CLASS
```

Results I get are the same as your results;

```
    Closed       SumOfAcreage      SumOfTonnage
    PLANTCANE    19.29048          162.504
    RATOON        6.59599           62.102
```

Comment: I need to sum all tonnage and acreage where field ids are equal once they have a max status of 3 @ChrisCarroll

Comment: change "= 3" to "<= 3", that will give results for all IDs with a max of 3.

Comment: The use of the INNER JOIN ensures that the cp.FIELD_ID must exist in the DT table, and then the <=3 will take any that exist in both tables with a max status of 3. Please mark as correct answer if this works. thanks

Comment: I am getting the correct acreage but the tonnage of the other field ids with parcel_status 1 and 2 don't seem to be summed. @ChrisCarroll

Comment: I've updated the script above to include the "<= 3" as I mentioned. parcel status of 1 & 2 are 100% included in results (anything less than or equal to 3 is included). I have also included my output results.

Comment: Can you please see the code i added. The last 2 are views i combine in a query to get data. However my first code block code does not show the same results as yours . @ChrisCarroll

Comment: First thing i notice is you have "=3" instead of the "<=3" that we discussed twice. Other than that I can't help too much with the views as there are fields mentioned that aren't in the sample data you supplied, so I don't know what they could be causing. 1 tip though is to remove the TOP 100 PERCENT and the ORDER BY from vCurrentParcelStatus. This is not needed, you are ordering the data in your other script anyway. it shouldn't be ordered twice in same query (unless you need to apply row numbers or something which you don't).